# MixRGB Node - RGB vs HSV

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders, color

While watching this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=91UDQnrZMqA), the author mentions the difference between HSV and RGB at [timestamp 4:09](https://youtu.be/91UDQnrZMqA?t=241). The thing is, when he adjusts the value slider to 0.5, the RGB values change to 0.214. When i tried this on my own, the value and the RGB is still the same. Why is this? For instance if I set the value to 0.5, RGB is also 0.5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That video is using Blender 2.83. However, since then, Blender changed the HSV sliders from "color picking space" to "scene linear space".

See https://developer.blender.org/rBf193b1afb313bcb937a396f09da2b9903a0d2fc3.